# tomcat7 web servlet wouldn't work

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

So I'm using eclipse and wrote 2 separate project. My servlet project is using the JAR file from the other project and it runs fine on the tomcat server built in to eclipse. However, if I package the servlet project into a WAR file and deploy it on the tomcat7 directly on my machine (not through eclipse), then it wouldn't run. I'm worried it might be some problem with the classpath. When I ran in eclipse, I had to manually went in RunConfiguration and add those jar files into the tomcat server classpath. How would I do that through command line?

Comment: Consider using Apache Maven for your application. It is much more easier to manage dependencies and JARS. Can be found at http://maven.apache.org

Comment: I did use maven for both of my eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mess with the tomcat classpath. Put the jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your war, as all the other libraries that your webapp uses.

Comment: I did do that and I checked to make sure they're all there. The problem is when I deploy it directly through command line, I can't debug it like when I do it through eclipse. I'm really not sure quite this is happening.